# How does the filter operation of Spark work on GraphX edges?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I'm very new to Spark and don't really know the basics, I just jumped into it to solve a problem. The solution for the problem involves making a graph (using GraphX) where edges have a string attribute. A user may wish to query this graph and I handle the queries by filtering out only those edges that have the string attribute which is equal to the user's query.

Now, my graph has more than 16 million edges; it takes more than 10 minutes to create the graph when I'm using all 8 cores of my computer. However, when I query this graph (like I mentioned above), I get the results instantaneously (to my pleasant surprise).

So, my question is, how exactly does the filter operation search for my queried edges? Does it look at them iteratively? Are the edges being searched for on multiple cores and it just seems very fast? Or is there some sort of hashing involved?

Here is an example of how I'm using filter: Mygraph.edges.filter(_.attr(0).equals("cat")) which means that I want to retrieve edges that have the attribute "cat" in them. How are the edges being searched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How can the filter results be instantaneous?

Running your statement returns so fast because it doesn't actually perform the filtering. Spark uses lazy evaluation: it doesn't actually perform transformations until you perform an action which actually gathers the results. Calling a transformation method, like `filter` just creates a new RDD that represents this transformation and its result. You will have to perform an *action* like `collect` or `count` to actually have it executed:

```scala
def myGraph: Graph = ???

// No filtering actually happens yet here, the results aren't needed yet so Spark is lazy and doesn't do anything
val filteredEdges = myGraph.edges.filter()

// Counting how many edges are left requires the results to actually be instantiated, so this fires off the actual filtering
println(filteredEdges.count)

// Actually gathering all results also requires the filtering to be done
val collectedFilteredEdges = filteredEdges.collect
```

Note that in these examples the filter results are not stored in between: due to the laziness the filtering is repeated for both actions. To prevent that duplication, you should look into Spark's caching functionality, after reading up on the details on transformations and actions and what Spark actually does behind the scene: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations.

## How exactly does the filter operation search for my queried edges (when I execute an action)?

in Spark GraphX the edges are stored in a an RDD of type `EdgeRDD[ED]` where `ED` is the type of your edge attribute, in your case `String`. This special RDD does some special optimizations in the background, but for your purposes it behaves like its superclass `RDD[Edge[ED]]` and filtering occurs like filtering any RDD: it will iterate through all items, applying the given predicate to each. An RDD however is split into a number of partitions and Spark will filter multiple partitions in parallel; in your case where you seem to run Spark locally it will do as many in parallel as the number of cores you have, or how much you have specified explicitly with `--master local[4]` for instance.

The RDD with edges is partitioned based on the [`PartitionStrategy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.PartitionStrategy) that is set, for instance if you create your graph with `Graph.fromEdgeTuples` or by calling `partitionBy` on your graph. All strategies are based on the edge's vertices however, so don't have any knowledge about your attribute, and so don't affect your filtering operation, except maybe for some unbalanced network load if you'd run it on a cluster, all 'cat' edges end up in the same partition/executor and you do a `collect` or some shuffle operation. See the [GraphX docs on Vertex and Edge RDDs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#vertex-and-edge-rdds) for a bit more information on how graphs are represented and partitioned.

Comment: I didn't think there was a need to show anything that I did. I just want to know how the edges are being searched when I use a filter. I mean, when I call Mygraph.edges.filter(_.attr(0).equals("cat")), how are the edges that have the attribute "cat" being searched?

Comment: Yeah, saying Spark does lazy evaluation says nothing about how values are partitioned and distributed when the filter is actually applied.

Comment: Fair enough, I focused on the question's initial trigger: that he saw instantaneous return, which now with the call added shows that there was no filtering in the first place. Try `Mygraph.edges.filter(_.attr(0).equals("cat")).count()` to see how long filtering actually takes. I have done a quick edit now with basic answer for this case, I can go into more depth a bit later.

Comment: I have many other lazy operations that need to be performed before filtering. Before asking the user to input a query, I run this exact "dummy" query just to force the code to execute; all the operations required to create the graph are then executed in about 11 minutes. Then, I ask the user for an input query. Then, this operation: Mygraph.edges.filter(_.attr(0).equals(inputQuery)) returns the edges instantaneously, even though more than 16 million edges need to searched.

Comment: I just read your edit. So basically, the graph is partitioned into multiple cores and the filter iterates through all the edges in all the cores?

Comment: Pretty much. I have extended a bit further, hopefully helping a bit more. So are you sure the edges are returned instantaneously, do you actually print them or show them? Because just that operation does not return the edges, just an RDD that represents the operation to be executed, you have to do a `collect` or `count` or something on that RDD to actually do the filtering.

Comment: Yes, after I filter out the edges, I collect them and separate the vertices and print out all the unique ones. Each query I run, I get the output almost immediately. Just last night I decided to test this code on EC2 with only 2 cores and still, after the graph is created (it takes 33 minutes on 2 cores), I get the results immediately. On 8 cores, I get it that there's a lot of parallel searching, but on just TWO cores? It seems way too fast